# Streaming a text file in web socket

Tags: python, websocket, streaming

I wrote a code in python 3.9.0 which opens a text file, read line by line and host it at web socket for clients to consume. It works just fine. The problem is, when I consume the file from the web socket server it is really slow. I can see that server sends it faster in thousands but client is receiving it slow. I am not sure what am I doing wrong with my client code. Here is my client code

```
async def consumeStream():
    while True:
        async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:6800') as ws:
            ingestCounter = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    consumedStream = await ws.recv()
                except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                    print(color.red+'Websocket connection closed, retrying !'+color.reset)
                    break

                if ingestCounter % 100 == 0:
                    print('\r'+f'Consuming: {ingestCounter}', end='')

                ingestCounter += 1
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Is streaming good idea with web sockets? Should I use Flask or FastAPI with yield ? What is the best practice for web sockets streaming and consuming ?